# Handle hashmark in Play 2.0 routes.conf

Tags: html, playframework, uri

I've to manage that kind of URL:

```
http://localhost:9000/oauth2callback#state=/&access_token=ya29.....
```

My Play 2.0's routes.conf looks like this:

```
GET     /oauth2callback             controllers.Application.testGoogleCallback(access_token: Option[String])
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the **#state=/** part of the URL makes the **access_token** param of the **testGoogleCallback** action being not filled in (but the rule matches and the action is well called).

Following URL works as aspected, and I correctly get the **access_token** param in the Action.

```
http://localhost:9000/oauth2callback?access_token=ya29.....
```

Any idea on how to specify that a fragment identifier is part of the URL in the routes.conf file?

Thx in advance

RP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hashmark is interpreted by the browser as a local anchor, and is not sent to the server. This is not a playframework specific problem, but part of the URI spec.

Is there any specific reason why you need it to be a hashmark? Your URL that works is valid HTML syntax, which is what I would expect to see!?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) names URI part after hashmark `#` a *fragment identifier* and says next:

> As such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and **thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent**, regardless of the URI scheme.

which means that fragment identifier is handled by the browser and it is not even send to the server.